# Ignore some times in DateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, datetimepicker

I'm using https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ for my website.

```
jQuery('.scw_datetime_from').datetimepicker({ format: 'd/m/Y H:i' });
```

And I have two times `20/11/2018 10:00` and `20/11/2018 18:00` I need when choose date `20/11/2018` the time picker will ignore times from `10:00` to `18:00`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
jQuery('.scw_datetime_from').datetimepicker({
  format:'d/m/Y H:i',  
  onChangeDateTime:function(dp){

  if( dp.dateFormat('d/m/Y')=="20/11/2018" ){
    this.setOptions({
       allowTimes:['00:00','01:00','02:00','03:00','04:00','05:00','06:00','07:00','08:00','09:00','10:00','19:00','20:00','21:00','22:00','23:00']
        });
    }
  }
 });
```

Comment: thanks, but the times from 10:00 to 18:00 only ignore when date is 20/11/2018

Comment: Yes I found it, but not work with onChangeDateTime, I used onSelectDate and it's ok, thank you.